# remove overlapping entries from a table KDB+/Q

Tags: kdb

I have two tables, called table1 and table2. Both have date and id as columns, and table2 is a small subset of table1 entries. How do I remove all entries that exist in table2 from table1 by matching up date and id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select from table1 where not([]date;id)in table2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/ Begin with example input of 10 entries 
q)t1:([]date:.z.d+til 10;id:til 10;c:til 10)
/ Pick 3 random entries to form key table t2
q)t2:3?delete c from t1
/ Key t1 by date and id and drop entries matching t2
q)t2 _ `date`id xkey t1
```